# OpenCV Python: Restarting a video

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture, frame-rate

I am new to both OpenCV and Python, and I am trying to create a simple program that will read in a video file named 'SixtyFPS.mov' and replay the video when it has reached its end. Ideally I would like to have the video loop continuously. I have not been able to find a solution for this online, however most of the answers I see involve using cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 1) or something of that nature in order to reset the frames. If anyone can explain to me how to use the cap.set feature in order to restart the video that would be greatly appreciated.

```
# The video 'SixtyFPS.mov' was recorded on an iPhone 7 at 60 FPS
# The video has a length of roughly 4 seconds long and so the total number
# of frames should be ~240, however my number_of_frames variable is equal to 115
# I am looking for a way to restart the video once it has reached its end but 
# I have not yet discovered a good method for doing so. Any advice would be 
# greatly appreciated. I am using Python 3.6.4 and OpenCV 3.3.1
# I needed to rotate the video so that it would be viewed in portrait 
# orientation rather than landscape


import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load in the video
video_cap = cv2.VideoCapture('SixtyFPS.mov')

# display the total number of frames. Should be ~240 and not 115
number_of_frames = int(video_cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
print("The total number of frames is: " + str(number_of_frames))

# Check if video opened successfully
if (video_cap.isOpened() == False):
    print("Error opening video file")

frame_counter = 0

# Read until video is completed
while(video_cap.isOpened()):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_cap.read()
    if ret == True:

        frame_counter += 1

        # resize the window
        resized_vid = cv2.resize(frame, (720, 1280))

        # Convert the video to grayscale
        grayscale_vid = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Change the orientation from landscape to portrait by rotating
        (h, w) = grayscale_vid.shape[:2]
        center = (w / 2, h / 2)
        M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, 270, 1.0)
        rotated_video = cv2.warpAffine(grayscale_vid, M, (w, h))

        # Display the rotated video
        cv2.imshow('Pitch', rotated_video)

        # trying to restart the video when the frame_counter
        # reaches its maximum value of 110
        if frame_counter >= 110:
            # here is where I think I need to restart the video
            # by setting the current frame to zero 


        # Press Q on keyboard to exit
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    # Break the loop
    else: 
        break

# When everything done, release the video capture object
video_cap.release()

# Closes all the frames
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this question has been posted, but just in case someone stumbled upon this answer, this code snippet with `cap.set()` worked for me. I relied on the documentation that can be found [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a8c6d8c2d37505b5ca61ffd4bb54e9a7c) (cpp) and [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html) (python).

```py
import cv2

# Get video handle.
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("path/to/video")
if not cap.isOpened():
  print("Cannot initialize cap.")
  exit()

# Get length of the video.
video_length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
# Initialize count.
count = 0

# Frames loop.
while True:
  # Check length of the video.
  if count == video_length:
    # Reset to the first frame. Returns bool.
    _ = cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)
    count = 0
  
  # Get the frame.
  success, image = cap.read()
  if not success:
    print("Cannot read frame.")
    break

  # do something with the image.
  cv2.imshow("Frame", image)

  # Quit by pressing 'q'.
  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
  count += 1

# Post loop.
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I used the above to go some `n` number of frames back by combining `cap.get()` and `cap.set()`.

Comment: all the usual points apply here. there's no check for `isOpened()`. there's no check on `success` from `cap.read()`. there is no reason to read the first frame outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general way how the video can be resized to `480 x 800` (height x width) and made to loop.

```
import cv2

# Change this path to your video location
path = "path_to_your_video"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
        ret, img = cap.read()

    img = cv2.resize(img, (800, 480))
    cv2.imshow("Video", img)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```